# Multiple Bars main background fill option, covers loading bars, how to fix it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using google translator, so errors may occur.

My problem: when I add a parameter with the „fillColor: '#f4f5f9'”, the wheel covers one of the elements of Multiple Bars.

I use converted from 4 to 2 Multiple Bars from the page below:
https://github.com/pguso/jquery-plugin-circliful

The same problem also occurs in the original script.
Demo of the original: https://jsfiddle.net/0c8qaqaj/41/

Below are pictures showing what is currently and what I would like to achieve.

http://samefakty.pl/plik.jpg

```
 <div class="row">
       <div class="col-lg-2">
           <div id="test-circle6">
               <div id="textInner">
                   <div>3h 20'</div>
                   <div>2h</div>
               </div>
           </div>
           <div id="test-circle7">
               <div id="textInner">
                   <div>4h 35'</div>
                   <div>3h 20'</div>
               </div>
           </div>          
       </div>
   </div>
<script>
   $( document ).ready(function() { // 6,32 5,38 2,34

       $("#test-circle6").circliful({
           animation: 1,
           animationStep: 5,
           foregroundBorderWidth: 10,
           backgroundBorderWidth: 20,
           textSize: 28,
           textStyle: 'font-size: 12px;',
           textColor: '#666',
           multiPercentage: 1,
           percentages: [
               {'percent': 32, 'color': '#e94e25'},
               {'percent': 20, 'color': '#878786'}
           ],
           multiPercentageLegend: 1,
           replacePercentageByText: '',
           backgroundColor: 'none',
           fillColor: 'none',
           icon: 'none',
           iconPosition: 'middle'
       });

       $("#test-circle7").circliful({
           animation: 1,
           animationStep: 5,
           foregroundBorderWidth: 10,
           backgroundBorderWidth: 20,
           textSize: 28,
           textStyle: 'font-size: 12px;',
           textColor: '#666',
           multiPercentage: 1,
           percentages: [
               {'percent': 43, 'color': '#e94e25'},
               {'percent': 32, 'color': '#878786'}
           ],
           multiPercentageLegend: 1,
           replacePercentageByText: '',
           backgroundColor: 'none',
           fillColor: '#f4f5f9',
           icon: 'none',
           iconPosition: 'middle'
       });     

   });
</script>
```

I tried to fix it but I can't, please give me a hint or help in solving it.

Thank you and best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after looking at the code it seems like fill color recursively adds circles with color. The close solution is to hide **fillColor circles** other than 1st, using jquery itself.

Just add this to in end of jquery document selector

```
  $("[fill='red']").slice(1).css("display", "none");
```

*Replace red with the fillColor value*

checkout  https://jsfiddle.net/52z0paw1/